# ¿Cuál es el equivalente de una petición GET con AJAX en JQuery para JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Lo que quiero es volver una petición que hice en jQuery, a Javascript.
El código de YouMightNotNeedjQuery no me ha funcionado, quiero poder hacer exactamente lo mismo que hago con mi petición jQuery, pero con Javascript.

Código jQuery:

```
function leer(user){
    
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "API/clientes.php",
        Type: "json",
        data: { usuario: user}
    }).done(function( data ) {
        var objeto= $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(objeto,function( index, element ) {
            var body = $('table tbody');
            body.append(
                "<tr>"+
                    "<td>"+element.nombre+'</td>'+
                "</tr>"
            );
        })
    })
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php require_once('conexion.php'); ?>
 <?php   
    if(isset($_GET["usuario"]) && $_GET['usuario'] == "soyReynald"){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        $arreglo = array();

        while( $mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
            array_push($arreglo, $mostrar);
        }
        echo( json_encode($arreglo) );
    }
?>
<?php require_once('desconectar.php'); ?>
```

Lo que busco hacer con JavaScript, es pedir por AJAX un archivo PHP y consumirlo como un API, trate de hacerlo con el siguiente código pero no me funcionó:

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'API/clientes.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    var data = {usuario: user}
    
    request.onload = function() {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        // Success!
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.response);
        obj.forEach(element => {
            var body = document.querySelector('table tbody');
            body.append(
                "<tr>"+
                    "<td>"+element.nombre+'</td>'+
                "</tr>"
            );
        });
        } else {
            alert("An error");
    
        }
    };

    request.send(data);
```

Comment: ya no es necesario hacerlo con `new XMLHttpRequest();` puedes utilizar directamente la api [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) que es mucho mas sencillo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En un `GET` y las variables se deben enviar como parámetros de búsqueda (`query params`) en la `URL`

### Solución:

Podrías usar [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) para convertir el objeto a una cadena.

#### Ejemplo:

```
var data = {usuario: user};

// ACA agregamos las variables por GET
var url = 'API/clientes.php?' + new URLSearchParams(data).toString();

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// Pasamos la URL con query params
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
request.onload = function() {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.response);
    obj.forEach(element => {
        var body = document.querySelector('table tbody');
        body.append(
            "<tr>"+
                "<td>"+element.nombre+'</td>'+
            "</tr>"
        );
    });
    } else {
        alert("An error");

    }
};

request.send();
```

---

#### Alternativa [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)

```
var data = {usuario: user};
var url = new URL('API/clientes.php');
url.search = new URLSearchParams(data).toString();

fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
   var body = document.querySelector('table tbody');
   data.forEach(element => {
     body.append("<tr>"+"<td>"+element.nombre+'</td>'+"</tr>");
   });
})
.catch(function(error) {
  alert("An error: " + error.message);
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, en cuanto llegue a casa lo pruebo y te califico.